# Calling between multiple Matlab instances or threads

Tags: multithreading, matlab, matlab-deployment

Basically, I need a way to call Matlab functions from an indefinitely-long separate thread.

First, I'm aware that I could use the TCPIP or UDP functionality to communicate between two instances of Matlab. I'll explain why that doesn't really help.

**Background:** I've written a Matlab class that acts as an interface for a USB device. Matlab was chosen because I need it to run on Mac/Linux/Windows, and the target users are only familiar with Matlab. Because of some inconsistencies in Matlab across platforms, I'm not using the `BytesAvailableFcn` or `BytesAvailableFcnMode` (I need as near realtime as possible, and with the aforementioned there can be delays up to 100s of milliseconds to send and receive data), and am instead sending and polling the port at a fixed interval using a timer. This introduces some overhead, and, if the user holds onto the main thread, the sending/receiving will also stop. Now, one of the most important function of the class is to set callbacks that are based on the input received from the device. The user sets their function and a given condition to match, and the object will call it automatically.

**Problem:** This object works well, completely in the background. However, as mentioned, it consumes some resources on the Matlab thread. I'm curious about making just the serial wrapper and callback functionality run on its own thread. However, if I compile it as a standalone application (for all 3 platforms) I believe my only solution will be TCPIP/UDP communication. Which then requires the object running on the main thread to poll the port in order to handle the callbacks in realtime - thus negating the benefit of moving it to a standalone application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could write the tool in Java, running in its own thread, and control the Java tool from within MATLAB. MATLAB interfaces really nicely with Java, since the whole UI is written in Java.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I was curious about that. However, given the 3 platforms, I assume that I would have to learn how to interface with the hardware in Java - which is something I may not have sufficient time to do. I'm curious if it might be possible to do the heavy lifting and compile the Matlab code to Java using the Coder(?) package, and then add the functionality to talk to Matlab (mainly receive function calls, and call runtime functions).

Answer (score 1):

Threading in matlab is a nightmare.  Doing anything in realtime, with the kind of latencies you're describing is not advised.  Under the hood, Matlab uses Java for all it's platform independence.  If you want to do this right, you'll write your app natively in Java, and call your java from Matlab (to deal with the fact that your users are incapable of installing a JRE, but can install matlab.)

That said, there is a better way to handle callbacks than what you are doing.  My preferred architecture in this scenario is to have one thread service the hardware, and communicate with other threads via message queues (one for input, one for output, and one for command/control if you need to get super fancy.)  Basically, the hardware thread then just focuses on servicing the queues.  You have a second thread handle the callbacks.  It reads the output queue of the hardware thread, and services the callbacks.   I've never done this in matlab (see first paragraph) but it works very well in Java contexts.

Comment: Okay, I can see adding an additional thread as an intermediary between Matlab and the hardware thread.